# Include equation align inside block in Beamer

Tags: beamer, math-mode, amsmath

I have the following Beamer document, but I get errors in the frame shown. Any ideas what the problem might be and how to solve it?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\usepackage{sourcesanspro}
\usepackage[amssymb,amsfonts]{concmath}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\renewcommand{\emph}[1]{{\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}#1}}

\renewcommand{\O}{\mathcal{O}}
\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb{Z}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Group structure}
  \begin{block}{Torsion structure}
    Let $E$ be defined over an algebraically closed field $\bar{k}$ of
    characteristic $p$.
    \begin{align*}
      E[m] \simeq\quad& \ZZ/m\ZZ\times\ZZ/m\ZZ  &\text{if p\nmid m,}\\[1em]
                 &\ZZ/p^e\ZZ & \text{\emph{ordinary} case,}\\[-1.7em]
      E[p^e] \simeq\Biggl\{& \\[-1.7em]
               \begin{cases}
                 &\{\O\} & \text{\emph{supersingular} case.}
               \end{cases}
    \end{align*}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error is that `\text` puts its content in text mode so you need `$` to get back to math

```
 \text{if $p\nmid m$,}
```

The second error is that `cases` is a two-column alignment so you can only have one `&` you could use

```
           \begin{cases}
             \{\O\} & \text{\emph{supersingular} case.}
           \end{cases}
```

which has one `&` so error free but a `cases` alignment with only one row doesn't serve any purpose, so I am not sure of the intended layout there.